# Reshape a numpy array so the columns wrap below the original rows

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

Consider the following scenario:

```
a = np.array([[1,1,1,3,3,3], [2,2,2,4,4,4]])
np.reshape(a, (4, 3))
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [4, 4, 4]])
```

Desired output:

```
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4]])
```

How can I reshape the array so the rows stay paired together and the overflowing columns wrap below the existing rows?
[image]

Comment: `reshape` can't do that.  Reshape just reinterprets the existing elements.  It doesn't change their order.  You CAN do this, by chopping it into 2 arrays and concatenating them.

Comment: reshape to (2,2,3), switch/swap/transpose the first 2 dim, and reshape to (-1,3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I described in the comments.  You can combine that into one statement:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,1,1,3,3,3], [2,2,2,4,4,4]])

a1 = a[:,:3]
a2 = a[:,3:]
a3 = np.concatenate((a1,a2))
print(a3)
```

Output:

```
[[1 1 1]
 [2 2 2]
 [3 3 3]
 [4 4 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.hstack(a.T.reshape(2,3,2)).T

print(a)
```

**Output**:

```
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4]])
```